# How can I select records n-at-a-time for multiple users to edit?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using a **Django** backend with **postgresql**.

Let's say I have a database with a table called `Employees` with about 20,000 records.

I need to allow multiple users to edit and verify the `Area Code` field for every record in `Employees`.

I'd prefer to allow a user to view the records, say, 30 at a time (to reduce burnout).

How can I select 30 records at a time from `Employees` to send to the front end UI for editing, **without letting multiple users edit the same records, or re-selecting a record that has already been verified**?

I don't need comments on the content of the database (these are example table and field names).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add 2 more fields to your table, say for example `assigned_to` and `verified`. You can update `assigned_to`, which can be a foreign key to the verifying user, when you allow the user to view that Employee. This will create a record preventing the Employee from being chosen twice. `assigned_to` can also double as a record of who verified this Employee for future reference.

`verified` could be simply a Boolean field which keeps track if the Employee has already been verified and can be updated when the user confirms the verification

The actual selects can be done like this:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(assigned_to=None, verified=False)[:30]
```

Then

```
for emp in employees:
        emp.assigned_to = user
        emp.save()
```

Note: This can still potentially cause a race condition if 2 users make this request at exactly the same time. To avoid this, another possibility could be to partition the employee tables into groups for each user with no overlap. This would ensure that no 2 users would ever have the same employees

Comment: Does this update the database automatically? If so, I think this will help a lot

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? The database does update when you perform actions in your views

Comment: I had read about queries taking "snapshots" of the database and acting upon that snapshot rather than the current version, but I was confused. What you said works just fine, thanks.

I'll mark it as solved once I implement it.